# run code on failure

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I have put

```
set -e
set -u
```

at the top of my BASH script to make it fail as opposed to going on.

Is there a way for me to specify some code to be run on failure?

---

If there's no better way, I can make my program `a` three files:

```
a
.a
.a_onfail
```

and have `a` just be

```
# headers etc
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
$(DIR)/.a || $(DIR)/.a_onfail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try solve this using [trap](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html). Eg: `trap "ERROR=1" ERR` and `trap '[ "$ERROR" = "1" ] && on_error' EXIT` and then provide a `on_error` function.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
trap ... ERR
```

> If a sigspec is ERR, the command arg is executed whenever a simple command has a non-zero  exit status,

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `trap '...' ERR` does not work with unset variables.

You can use a subshell instead of two separate script files:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu

main() {
  echo "$X"
}

on_failure() {
  echo "Failure"
}

(main) || on_failure
```